How do I find the X most closest objects to transform.position?
This code shows how I find the single closest object (e.g. collider) within a group of hit colliders. I'd like to find the closest 4 objects. (this number might increase)
        Collider closestCollider = null;
        float closestColliderDistance = float.PositiveInfinity;

        foreach (Collider collider in hitColliders)
        {
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(collider.transform.position, transform.position);
            if (distance < closestColliderDistance)
            {
                closestColliderDistance = distance;
                closestCollider = collider;
            }
        }
        if (closestCollider != null)
        {
            // handle it
        }


So I want to return a group (e.g. an array) of the 4 closest objects to transform.position. This doesn't need to be sorted. It can be based on this code or completely new code.
Maybe it could involve some kind of list that is sorted by distance then get the top X items. Maybe linq? (not sure how to use it)

What's the question?

I updated the title to be a question

Linq is a MS library.  Is this C# or some other language with a related syntax.

if you need 4 items returned, looks like you need to keep track of the top 4, i dont see anything here doing that, this only gets the 1..

@Bart that's for path finding and graphs with nodes etc .. in this case here OP simply wants to find the closest targets within the given collection by distance in 3D space .. that's way simpler ;)

cup - this is for Unity C#. People sometimes use linq with unity

BugFinder - yes the example code only gets the top 1. I am wanting other people to provide code that will find the top 4.

Well yes simply sort by distance and than take X items
var xClosestItems = hitColliders
    .OrderBy(o => (o.transform.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude)
    .Take(X)
    .ToList();

where X means up to the desired amount - can be less if hitColliders doesn't have enough items.
Some notes

comparing sqrMagnitude is more efficient than Distance which has to take the square root. As distance is always positive we can go by a² > b² => a > b

currently this takes the distance by pivot point (transform position). This might differ from the gravitational center collider.bounds.center

generally ToList is a bit more efficient than ToArray in exchange to bigger memory consumption as it doesn't have to shorten the underlying array to match the exact length but simply goes in 2eX increments



Note I actually used HashSet instead of hitColliders and it still worked.

@LukeWenke of course it does as any Component has the transform property
